# R - Need different result after using lapply

Tags: r

i need your help again. How can i adapt my code to get only ONE final dataframe (jointdataset) after every file in `path` was merged to the intial dataframe `knime.in`. I know `lapply` will in this case return a list of dataframes but i am not able to change the syntax with `apply` ect. without errors. If i try this i get this error message: "match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing with no default"

```
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")

path ="C:/.../"
path2 ="C:/..."
files <- list.files(path, full.names=T)

knime.in <- read.csv(file=path2, header=TRUE, sep = ";")

dfList <- lapply(files, function(i) {
  df <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, col.names=c("Column.0", "Column.1"), sep = ";",row.names=NULL)
  name =substr(i,sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = "/", i), tail, 1)[1]+1,nchar(i)-4)
  jointdataset <-merge(knime.in, df_2, by.x=name, by.y ='Column.0',all = TRUE)
  jointdataset <- jointdataset[ , ! names(jointdataset) %in% c(name)]
  names(jointdataset)[names(jointdataset)=="Column.1"] <- name
  print(name)
  return(jointdataset)
  })
```

Hope you can help me out with this again. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to only extract the final result `dfList <- dfList[[length(dfList)]]`. But a **better** approach would be replacing `lapply` with a `for-loop`

```
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")
library(data.table) # for setnames
path ="C:/.../"
path2 ="C:/..."
files <- list.files(path, full.names=T)

knime.in <- knime.out <- read.csv(file=path2, header=TRUE, sep = ";")

for(i in files){
  name <- substr(i,sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = "/", i), tail, 1)[1]+1,nchar(i)-4)
  knime.out <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, col.names=c("Column.0", "Column.1"), sep = ";",row.names=NULL) %>% 
   full_join(knime.out, by.x = name, by.y = 'Column.0') %>%
   select(-!!sym(name)) %>% 
   setnames('Column.1', name, TRUE) #Change 'Column.1' to name and skip all other columns = TRUE

}
```

Note that I could not test this as your question is not reproducible, so there may be typos or errors. I've replaced `merge` with `full_join` (`all = TRUE`) and I'm using `setnames` from `data.table` to perform column renaming. `-!!sym(name)` should convert your `name` variable to an enquoted symbol, needed for `tidy-select` functions.

This way you'll end with `knime.in` and `knime.out`.

***Beware!!***
Using `full_join`, `merge(..., all = TRUE)` and similar leads to explosive behaviour, and you are likely to experience memory issues even for small number of files each with small number of observations. Often you only need `left_join`, `right_join` or `inner_join` to merge exclusively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! like you said it's hard to test when the question is not reproducible. I tried your code and i get this error:  "by` must be supplied when `x` and `y` have no common variables. i use by = character()` to perform a cross-join."

Comment: btw i am getting this Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-`%>%`(...)
 2. +-data.table::setnames(., "Column.1", name, TRUE)
 3. | \-base::is.data.frame(x)
 4. +-dplyr::select(., -!!sym(name))
 5. +-dplyr::full_join(., knime.out, by.x = name, by.y = "Column.0")
 6. \-dplyr:::full_join.data.frame(., knime.out, by.x = name, by.y = "Column.0")
 7.   \-dplyr:::join_mutate(...)
 8.     \-dplyr:::join_cols(...)
 9.       \-dplyr:::standardise_join_by(by, x_names = x_names, y_names = y_names)

Comment: Ah, apologies. `full_join` (and other joins in `dplyr` only takes a single named character vector of `x.side = y.side`. So it would be something like `jcol <- c(´Column.0`); names(jcol) <- name; ... full_join(..., by = jcol)`. Check up on the function itself by lookin at `?dplyr::full_join` and the description there. My answer was a quick-and-dirty solution, and it is hard to really test it for errors. This one should be easy to fix by reading the argument list and description of the function.

Comment: Glad i could help out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

@KTTRLD

Try to use **sapply** instead **lapply**. So wil be:

```
dfList <- sapply(files, function(i) {
  df <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, col.names=c("Column.0", "Column.1"), sep = ";",row.names=NULL)
  name =substr(i,sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = "/", i), tail, 1)[1]+1,nchar(i)-4)
  jointdataset <-merge(knime.in, df_2, by.x=name, by.y ='Column.0',all = TRUE)
  jointdataset <- jointdataset[ , ! names(jointdataset) %in% c(name)]
  names(jointdataset)[names(jointdataset)=="Column.1"] <- name
  print(name)
  return(jointdataset)
  })
```

If didn't work, try to **data.frame** lapply's output, like this:

```
dfList <- data.frame(lapply(files, function(i) {
  df <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, col.names=c("Column.0", "Column.1"), sep = ";",row.names=NULL)
  name =substr(i,sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = "/", i), tail, 1)[1]+1,nchar(i)-4)
  jointdataset <-merge(knime.in, df_2, by.x=name, by.y ='Column.0',all = TRUE)
  jointdataset <- jointdataset[ , ! names(jointdataset) %in% c(name)]
  names(jointdataset)[names(jointdataset)=="Column.1"] <- name
  print(name)
  return(jointdataset)
  }))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i've tested your code but the sapply example gives me a large matrix/list [1024x2] back without any changes to the values. For the 'data.frame' example it seams like the `data.frame` expands itself again. So i end up with the initial size of the data.frame multiplied by the number of files that include.